# Duplication with OpenXML (word document) and ID issues

Tags: c#, xml, ms-word, openxml

Is it possible to duplicate a word document element with OpenXML without having any issues of "duplicate id" ?

Actually, to duplicate, I clone the elements inside the body and append the cloned elements in the body. But if any of the element have an ID, I'm having errors when I open the document in word.

Here is an example of error from OpenXML validator :

- [60] Description="Attribute 'id' should have unique value. Its
  current value 'Rectangle 11' duplicates with
  others."

And here is my code :

```
        Document document = wordDocument.MainDocumentPart.Document;
        Body body = document.Body;
        IEnumerable<OpenXmlElement> elements = ((Body)body.CloneNode(true)).Elements();

        foreach (var element in elements)
        {
            OpenXmlElement e = (OpenXmlElement)element.CloneNode(true);

            body.AppendChild(e);              
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't just copy elements with an id, you have to duplicate Parts too (search OpenXmlPart for more informations).

You can do this by combining functions `AddPart()` and `GetIdOfPart()` (accessible from `MainDocumentPart`)

**First try:**
when you have an element with an id, use `AddPart(OpenXmlPart part)` to add the element part and retrieve the new generated id of the part with `GetIdOfPart(OpenXmlPart part)`

After that, you can replace in your cloned OpenXmlElement the id by the new one

**Second try:**
or you could imagine an other way like:

- Check highest id of existing parts (and save it)
- Clone all parts from the start and choose yourself the id (by adding the highest saved id)
- When you copy each element and find an id, add the saved highest id to match with the new part

I hope one of this way will help you, but in any case you will need to clone parts

Comment: Do you have any example please ? I don't really know how to change the ID of an element. And about the parts, I just need to AddPart(e) in my case ?

Comment: You need to add a copy of the part (with AddPart), retrieve the new Id of the copied part (with GetIdOfPart) and replace the id in the copied element. To replace the Id you have to inspect your element (transform your OpenXmlElement into the real object and use the Id property to affect the new Id

Comment: Which part do I have to copy ? Since I'm iterating over a list of openxmlelement ? I don't really know how to do it.

Answer (score 0):

[DocIO](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/file-formats/docio) is a .NET class library that can read, write and render Microsoft Word documents. Using [DocIO](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/file-formats/docio), you can clone the elements such as paragraph, table, text run or the entire document and append it where you need.

The whole suite of controls is available for free (commercial applications also) through the [community license program](https://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense) if you qualify. The community license is the full product with no limitations or watermarks.

Herewith we have a given simple example code snippet which clone all the paragraphs and tables in the document body and append them at the end of the same document.

```
using Syncfusion.DocIO.DLS;

namespace DocIO_Clone
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (WordDocument document = new WordDocument(@"InputWordFile.docx"))
        {
            int sectionCount = document.Sections.Count;
            for (int i = 0; i < sectionCount; i++)
            {
                IWSection section = document.Sections[i];
                int entityCount = section.Body.ChildEntities.Count;
                for (int j = 0; j < entityCount; j++)
                {
                    IEntity entity = section.Body.ChildEntities[j];
                    switch(entity.EntityType)
                    { 
                        case EntityType.Paragraph:
                            IWParagraph paragraph = entity.Clone() as IWParagraph;
                            document.LastSection.Body.ChildEntities.Add(paragraph);
                            break;
                        case EntityType.Table:
                            IWTable table = entity.Clone() as IWTable;
                            document.LastSection.Body.ChildEntities.Add(table);
                            break;

                    }
                }
            }
            document.Save("ResultDocument.docx");
        }
    }
}
}
```

For further information, please refer our [help documentation](http://help.syncfusion.com/file-formats/docio/overview)

Note: I work for Syncfusion